# Edit the width/height in scrollbars in a template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I'm trying to edit the width (in vertical scroll) and height (in horizontal scroll) in a ScrollViewer template in WPF, I want to reduce them to 12 px but the value goes stuck in 17 px and I can't decrease it, why? I've tried everything but the result got damaged (the corner doesn't dissapear when needed, the ScrollBars get a strange design, etc.)

[image: The value is stuck in 17, it allows to increase, but not decrease]

The value is stuck in 17, it allows to increase, but not decrease

Comment: You need to modify Template of ScrollBar control and not ScrollViewer to change look of scroll bars.

Comment: @Nitesh I've reduced it too, but the grid row definition stills in 17.

Answer (score 4):

Set **MinWidth="10"** for Vertical ScrollBar and **MinHeight="10"** for Horizontal ScrollBar, or whatever value you want for scroll bars in ScrollViewer Template.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked it and was very useful, easy to customize, I've rated it +1 and accepted the answer.